# No DNS can be found in one virtual machine, while an other with almost similar configuration does work

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

I have a Virtualbox server running with multiple Virtualbox clients. By switching of ISP this did not work anymore. I asked online help, which moved to a good direction [Connect two subnets on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1007200/connect-two-subnets-on-linux) but without solving. With offline help, which unfortunately I can not reproduce, much was solved. But not all.

Virtual machine Vbox1a (Ubuntu) does work well :
External DNS works :

```
bernard@vbox1a:/etc/network$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.166.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wm-in-f147.1e100.net (64.233.166.147): icmp_req=1 ttl=63    time=15.3 ms
```

As well as internal DNS :

```
bernard@vbox1a:/etc/network$ ping www.mysite.com
PING www.mysite.com (192.168.1.73) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.73: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.68 ms
^C64 bytes from 192.168.1.73: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.611 ms
```

Virtual machine Vbox1a has following configuration :

```
bernard@vbox1a:/etc$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f1:68:9e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.90  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef1:689e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1263592 errors:0 dropped:344 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:244455084 (244.4 MB)  TX bytes:12573980 (12.5 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:79:02:34  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe79:234/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:446519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:303468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:196576684 (196.5 MB)  TX bytes:28701402 (28.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:257512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:257512 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20038093 (20.0 MB)  TX bytes:20038093 (20.0 MB)
```

And routing tables :

```
bernard@vbox1a:/etc/network$ ip route show
default via 10.0.3.2 dev eth1  proto static 
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.15  metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.90
```

And interfaces :

```
bernard@vbox1a:/etc/network$ cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.70 192.168.1.1

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.90
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

So far so good. So the only thing I had to do, I thought, copy these settings, with small adjustment, to an other Ubuntu virtual machine. But this does not work.

But Vbox11 (Ubuntu) does not work : 
DNS does not work :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

But ping to IP address (of www.google.com) does :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ ping 64.233.166.147
PING 64.233.166.147 (64.233.166.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 64.233.166.147: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=15.9 ms
```

With the following configuration :

```
bernard@vbox11:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b5:98:0b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.86  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb5:980b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5028 errors:0 dropped:26 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:494416 (494.4 KB)  TX bytes:51946 (51.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:246037 (246.0 KB)  TX bytes:246037 (246.0 KB)
```

And routing tables :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.86
```

And hosts :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   vbox11

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And interfaces :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.70 192.168.1.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.86
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

After I made changes to interfaces file I updated the using :

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

After suggestion of Marius Matutiae, dns-names should be part of eth0 instead of lo, I changed my interfaces into :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.86
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.70 192.168.1.1
```

Refresh the settings, and checked Google again, but without success :

```
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ sudo restart network-manager
network-manager start/running, process 3250
bernard@vbox11:/etc/network$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

So I must made a mistake somewhere. The server using local DNS as primary and the gateway DNS as secondary works fine, because it does work for Vbox1a. To me the settings looks very similar. I must have made a mistake somewhere but have no idea where, or how to search.

Comment: Can you explain what the two networks, 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.0.3.0724, are? What do they join? And can you show the two routing tables? `ip route show'.

Comment: I added the routing tables in the original question. The 192.168.1.0/24 is my local network. The 10.0.3.x is I believe, the old configuration and not used any more. The network IP addresses had to be changed in the past by external reason.

Comment: What is your firewall configuration?

Comment: I have no specific info. VM2 worked fine, using subnet range 192.168.0.x I changed from ISP which forced me to use subnet range 192.168.1.x I had no permission on the router to changed the DHCP. So I was forced to change individual VM manually. Which causes this problem. The Firewal was not changed. So I suspect this does not make a difference. But please correct me if I am wrong.